# Access UI Control from another class

Tags: ios, xamarin, background, nsurlsession

I would like to update my progress view from another class but dont know how to do that properly.

In my ViewController I have a button that start a task, which download a file from hardcoded link

```
public void downloadTask()
        {
            NSUrl url = NSUrl.FromString("https://www.dropbox.com/s/5fsciuo0nprzvu6/TestDoc.docx?dl=0");

            var config = NSUrlSessionConfiguration.DefaultSessionConfiguration;
            NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, (new SimpleSessionDelegate() as INSUrlSessionDelegate), new NSOperationQueue());
            var downloadTask = session.CreateDownloadTask(NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(url));

            downloadTask.Resume();
        }
```

In my SimpleSessionDelegate class I want to update my progress view in the DidWriteData method.

```
public class SimpleSessionDelegate : NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate
    {
        public override void DidFinishDownloading(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask, NSUrl location)
        {
            var documents = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            var destinationPath = Path.Combine(documents, "Sample.docx");

            if (File.Exists(location.Path))
            {
                NSFileManager fileManager = NSFileManager.DefaultManager;
                NSError error;

                fileManager.Remove(destinationPath, out error);

                bool success = fileManager.Copy(location.Path, destinationPath, out error);

                if (!success)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error during the copy: {0}", error.LocalizedDescription);
                }
            }
        }
        public override void DidWriteData(NSUrlSession session, NSUrlSessionDownloadTask downloadTask, long bytesWritten, long totalBytesWritten, long totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        {
            new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                InvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    //how to access UI?
                });
            })).Start();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You might be better to setup a timer within your ViewController that asks your SimpleSessionDelegate about the status of the file download every second or so and updates as required.

Comment: So update the progress view directly in the didWriteData method is a performance killer?

Comment: Main reason is to keep UI code out of your file downloading code. It’s cleaner

Comment: @R.Kut Hello, have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use Event to change your ViewController's UIProgressView's progress.

Firstly define an event in your ViewModel:

```
public delegate void DownloadProgressDelegate(float progress);
public event DownloadProgressDelegate DownloadEvent;
```

Secondly, pass this event to your download delegate file:

```
NSUrlSession session = NSUrlSession.FromConfiguration(config, (new SimpleSessionDelegate(DownloadEvent) as INSUrlSessionDelegate), new NSOperationQueue());
//Here is your SimpleSessionDelegate
event ViewModel.DownloadProgressDelegate DownloadEvent;
public SimpleSessionDelegate(ViewModel.DownloadProgressDelegate downloadEvent)
{
    DownloadEvent = downloadEvent;
}
```

Then you can trigger this event when the data coming in the menthod `DidWriteData()`:

```
float progress = (float)totalBytesWritten / totalBytesExpectedToWrite;
DownloadEvent(progress);
```

The last step is subscribe this event in your ViewController like:

```
var myViewModel = new ViewModel();
MyViewModel.DownloadEvent += (progress) =>
{
    MyProgress.Progress = progress;
};
myViewModel.downloadTask();
```

Comment: I cant pass an event to my SimpleSessionDelegate because the base class NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate has no such a constructor

Comment: @R.Kut You can create your own constructor with parameter downloadEvent.

Comment: yes in my SimpleSessionDelegate but not in NSUrlSessionDownloadDelegate because thats from metadata.

Comment: @R.Kut I simulate a task download in my sample [here](https://github.com/lt0526/UrlsessionDemo).

Comment: some additional information: calculate the right way float progress =  float()totalBytesExpectedToWrite / (float)totalBytesWritten and myProgressBar.SetProgress(progress, true);

Answer (score 2):

In your `Page.xaml` do this:

```
<ContentPage .... >
    ...
    <ProgressBar Progress="{Binding ProgValue, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    ...
</ContentPage>
```

Then in `Page.xaml.cs` do this:

```
...
public partial class Page : ContentPage
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = new PageViewModel();
}
...
```

Now you need `PageViewModel` class to create a way between your data(model) and you view:

```
using MvvmHelper;
using System;

namespace MyApp.ViewModels
{
    ...
    public class PageViewModel : BaseViewModel
    {
        ...
        public static int ProgValue { get; set; }
        ...
    }
}
```

Now if you update the value of ProgValue from every where of your app, it will automatically update the progress bar.

To use the BaseViewModel, you need to install
[Mvvm Helper](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Refractored.MvvmHelpers)
or in the package manager console type:
`Install-Package Refractored.MvvmHelpers`

This architecture is called MVVM (Model-View-View-Model) - formally known as MVC (Model-View-Controller)

Comment: where I can find the page.xaml? Its an iOS single view app

Comment: I wrote this sample for Xamarin.Forms for cross platform usage. In iOS specific projects, you have page.storyborad, read this apple developers document: [Connect UI to code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html)